# Unicoin mining and canvas clicking

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'd really like to automate unicoin mining so that it can go on in the background while I'm doing important things like answering questions on stackoverflow.  I notice that there is a `canvas#uc-rockcanvas` element where you can click the rocks.  Clicking down seems to add the class `md`, and then releasing the click removes `md`.

Is there any way to interact with specific elements of the canvas using JavaScript so that you can trigger clicks on them?

Comment: Maybe you could rig up a script that would let you target the clicks manually, and then the script would blast the rock.

Comment: I tried this, but the canvas only responded to the organic clicks

Comment: @JoshWillik: Probably a [trust problem](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events). Alas, my customizable deluxe rock blasting machine gun will live on in the unirealm.

Comment: I just bought Voting Animation and I will test it on your question. [edit] omg what was that. estuckouvrflaw pls y u do dis

Comment: Open up the JavaScript console and type in `addUnicoins(999)` and see what happens...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that no longer exists.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here a code I've got on META SE :

```
(function uniMine() {
  $.getJSON('/unicoin/rock', function(data) {
       setTimeout(function() {
          $.post('/unicoin/mine?rock=' + data.rock, 
            {fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey});
       }, 10000);
   });
  setTimeout(uniMine, 11000);
 })();
```

Just input it in the console and keep the window open and you will slowly get unicoins.

Not sure about the original author, I think it is Doorknob

Comment: When you run this script too long, your earnings will dwindle to a consistent 0 per request

Comment: @JoshWillik weird, i have it till this morning and im still getting some.... But it is really slow!

Comment: That may be only for me though. I got locked out of SO several times because of my own auto-miner development :P

Comment: Don't adjust the timeout values to lower. According to the feedback messages there's a 10 second rate limit anyway. Also, if you run this while you are on the field where you get the rocks, you'll get errors sometimes (conflicts) form the server. Run it simply at the main SO page instead.

Comment: Put it in the console? I think you mean COINSOLE! AMIRITE? AMIRITE?

Answer (score 91):

You absolutely have wrong preferences. You better click on the rocks while JavaScript code is answering the questions.

Comment: Why not both? Answering and clicking in Javascript

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible, JS is single-threaded

Comment: @Dr.Molle: If mining can be done with just AJAX calls, you can spawn a long-running web worker to handle that and do the answering in the main/DOM thread.

Answer (score 27):

```
(function uniMine()
 {
     $.getJSON('/unicoin/potato', function(data)
               {
                   setTimeout(function()
                              {
                                  $.post('/unicoin/mine?potato=' + data.potato, {fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey});
                              }, 10000);
               });
     setTimeout(uniMine, 11000);
 })();
```

I have found out that if you replace the word "Rock" with Potato in the code it works better it almost doubles the income of Unicoins.

Comment: I knew there was no way this could be true. But I was soooo hoping it was

Answer (score 11):

Paste this code in your [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) console..

The problem is solved for life1!

```
coinMeMaybe(9999);
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
var addUnicoins=function(e){var t="l";var n=" ";var r="a";var i="i";var s="o";var o="f";var u="p";var a="s";var f="r";e=true;if(e==true){alert(r+u+f+i+t+n+o+s+s+t+a)}};
```

And then be sure to call the function `addUnicoins(999);`. You can use any number you'd like.

Comment: There appears to be an off-by-one error in your addUnicoins function. When I call addUnicoins(999) I only get 998 unicoins

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with canvas clicking, but it does *sort of* solve your automation problem:

```
http://pastebin.com/6uR2cwpQ
```

This script will succeed around 30% of the time. You'll have to go digging through your requests to find your fkey though.

## Full code below

```
setInterval( function(){
    console.log( "firing" );
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/unicoin/rock",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            _: new Date().getTime()
        },
        success: function( o ){
            console.info( "Got rock " + o.rock );
            if( Math.random() < 0.4 ){
                console.info( "Ignoring this one" );
                return;
            }
            setTimeout( function(){
                console.log( "Attempting rock send" );
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://stackoverflow.com/unicoin/mine",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        rock: o.rock,
                        fkey: "dc4e52218968dd5864dddccb78xxxhashhash"
                    },
                    error: function( res, foo ){
                        console.error( foo );
                    },
                    success: function( e ){
                        if( e.value === 0 ){
                            console.warn( "No luck" );
                        } else {
                            console.log( e.result + ", you earned " + e.value + ' coins' );
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 3000 + (Math.random() * 1700) );
        }
    })
}, 6000 );

console.log( "starting up!" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy. Run the script in the console of your browser's developer tool and move the mouse cursor on the rock...

```
var elem = $('#uc-rockcanvas');
var x, y;

elem.mousemove(function (e) {
    x = e.pageX, y = e.pageY;
});

var trigger = function () {
    elem.trigger(jQuery.Event("mousedown", {
        pageX: x,
        pageY: y
    }));
}
setInterval(trigger, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the click events to be user-initiated (for security, obviously). You'll need to simulate the clicks at the OS level. On Windows (also security), I like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for this task.

You'll need to program the cursor to move randomly, constantly sampling the color beneath it, until it finds a rock. Then submitting many sequential clicks becomes trivial:

```
// from http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm
// MouseClick ( "button" [, x, y [, clicks = 1 [, speed = 10]]] )
MouseClick ("left", x, y, 50, 10)
```